# Complex Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

Find the moduli and argument of $(1+i)e^{\pi/6}$.

I converted $(1+i)$ to polar form, that is $\sqrt2e^{i\pi/4}$ and multiplied by $e^{i\pi/6}$ to obtain $\sqrt2e^{i5\pi/12}$. But am unsure how to find the argument from  $5\pi/12$.

Comment: the argument is $5\pi / 12$ and the moduli is $\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $z = r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta) = re^{i\theta}$, then $z$ has modulus $r$ and argument $\theta$. Can you take it from there?